# correct type specification for cloneable-like trait in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, static-typing

The question is not about `AnyRef.clone()`, it is about case with similar semantic.

I'd like to define an interface for classes that may create copy of itself:

```
trait Cloneable {
  def clone() : this.type
}

class Test(val store : Int) extends Cloneable {
  def clone() = new Test(store)
}
```

Path-dependent `this.type` would not work since `this.type` is different for the `Test` class type and for a class extending the `Test`. The descendant should then override clone method to match its own type.

How should I define type requirement for the Cloneable trait?

I've peeked into scala collections and found here tip: define `TestLike` trait, that handles type restrictions, and class `Test` that embodies corresponding trait.

I'd like to avoid unnecessary clumsiness if possible

---

trying self-recurring pattern as suggested:

```
trait Cloneable[A <: Cloneable[A]] {
  def clone() : A
}

class Store[A <: Cloneable[A]](val store : Int) extends Cloneable[A] {
  override def clone() : A = new Store[A](store)
}
```

failed with error:

```
Cloneable.scala:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Store[A]
 required: A
  override def clone() : A = new Store[A](store)
```

---

another issue in the recurring template: premature finalization

```
class Store(val store : Int) extends Cloneable[Store] {
  override def clone() = new Store(store)
}

class SubStore(store : Int, val stash : Double) extends Store(store)

val ss1 = new SubStore(1, 0.5)
val ss2 = ss1.clone()
assert(ss2.isInstanceOf[SubStore])
```

The issue with `SubStore` is with type system ignoring absent `clone()` method in the `SubStore` class although `SubStore` is the `Cloneable` descendant via `Store`. But the `Store` finalize `Cloneable` interface with type parameter `Store` and all its descendants lacks proper `clone()` method restriction

Comment: Not beautiful, but Scala's version of the C++ "CRTP" (curiously recurring template pattern): `trait Cloneable[A :< Cloneable[A]] { def clone(): A }`.

Comment: I've got an issue applying recurring template patter, and posted it in the updated questing

Comment: `class Store extends Cloneable[Store]`, `override def clone(): Store`

Comment: updated question with new issue

Comment: In your last code snippet `override def clone() : A = new Store[A](store)`, where A comes from? And Store doesn't take type parameters. And what is premature finalization?

Comment: that was shamefull copypast. fixed it.

Comment: How do you expect your case to work? It can't magically know to copy the `stash` field too. Inheritance is a PITA for stuff like this.

Comment: I expect that any class responding cloneable interface should return instance of own type. If a class does not provide appropriate clone method, type system should give me an error. It is what the type system is needed for.

Comment: The problem with subtyping and inheritance is that "return instance of own type" is still strictly true if it returns a supertype. There's no general way of saying "I'll only accept the most specific type that fits". Creating an invariant type parameter in a typeclass comes pretty close, and the answer below gives you that.

Answer (score 0):

Scala type variance allows to you implement what you need in a simple way, but you have to move away from inheritance and go to typeclasses.

```
trait Cloner[A]{
  def cloneObject(input:A):A
}
trait CloningFunctions{
  def cloneObject[A](input:A)(implicit cloner:Cloner[A]) = cloner.cloneObject(input)
}

object CloningFunctions extends CloningFunctions

class MyClass1(val b:Int)
class MyClass2(val a:Int,b:Int) extends MyClass1(b)

object Example {

  implicit val cloner = new Cloner[MyClass1]{
    def cloneObject(input: MyClass1): MyClass1 = new MyClass1(input.b)
  }

  import CloningFunctions._

  cloneObject(new MyClass2(3,4))

}
```

The idea here is that since Cloner[A] is invariant in type A, the following code won't compile:

could not find implicit value for parameter cloner: Cloner[MyClass2]
  cloneObject(new MyClass2(3,4))

because you have a Cloner[MyClass1] but not a Cloner[MyClass2] in scope.

While `cloneObject(new MyClass1(3))` will compile.