# Specify concrete type for methods in Scala trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, typing

I want to define a method in a Scala trait where both a parameter to the method and the return type correspond to the same concrete class which extends the trait. I've tried something like the following:

```
trait A {
  def foo(obj: this.type): this.type
}

final case class B(val bar: Int) extends A {
  override def foo(obj: B): B = {
    B(obj.bar + this.bar)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val b1 = new B(0)
    val b2 = new B(0)
    val b3: B = b1.foo(b2)
  }
}
```

However, trying to compile this code gives the following error:

```
Test.scala:5: error: class B needs to be abstract. Missing implementation for:
  def foo(obj: B.this.type): B.this.type // inherited from trait A
case class B(val bar: Int) extends A {
           ^
Test.scala:6: error: method foo overrides nothing.
Note: the super classes of class B contain the following, non final members named foo:
def foo: ((obj: _1.type): _1.type) forSome { val _1: B }
  override def foo(obj: B): B = {
               ^
2 errors
```

There's obviously something I'm misunderstanding about the Scala type system here. The signature of `foo` in class `B` is what I want it to be, but I don't know how to correctly define the method in `A` (or if this is even possible). It seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344262/correct-type-specification-for-cloneable-like-trait-in-scala) is asking something quite similar, but I don't immediately see how the answer applies in my situation.

Comment: There's always only one inhabitant of `this.type`, and it's `this`. Your "override" says "I'll take a B and return some, maybe other, instance of B" which is not specific enough.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov I do want to return some, maybe other instance of B. I realized my example was probably unclear since I didn't give any idea of what the foo method might look like. I updated the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type annotation `this.type` means that you may only return `this`. So in that case you may not return another instance of `B`, the same holds for the method parameter.

If this was just about the return type, a solution would be to require `foo` to return something of type `A`, the override method in `B` can specialize the return type to return `B`.

However since you also have an argument which you want to be of the type of the subtype you could use a [Self Recursive Type](https://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-self-recursive-types/). The following example compiles and should do what you want.

```scala
  trait A[S <: A[S]] {
    def foo(obj: S): S
  }

  case class B(val bar: Int) extends A[B] {
    override def foo(obj: B): B = {
      B(obj.bar + 1)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Changing the return type of `foo` in `A` to `A` instead of `this.type` gives a similar error.

Comment: Updated my answer, self recursive types seem to be a solution here

Comment: That does seem to solve this specific problem. Although obviously means adding a type parameter to `A`. This complicates use of `A` elsewhere so I would prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I agree that adding a type parameter to `A` complicates the use of `A` elsewhere. However this is inherent to the question asked: if you want "both a parameter to the method and the return type correspond to the same concrete class which extends the trait" then when calling the trait the compiler must be able to verify that the parameter is indeed of the correct type. For this the concrete subtype of the trait must be known at compile-time.

It might be worthwhile to investigate if it is possible to implement a solution where such a trait is not needed at all.

Comment: Agreed. It just seems like it should be possible for this second type parameter to be inferred instead of explicitly provided. But perhaps that is not possible in Scala.

Comment: In this specific example you do not use `this.bar` in the `foo` method of `B`. Would it perhaps be possible to change the signature of the `foo` method such that it does not have an argument? That might allow you to simplify your problem.

Comment: Good thought, although that was a flaw in my example which I have now updated.

Comment: Note, that this is not only ugly, but also doesn't actually work quite right. Consider `class C extends B` ... it compiles, but `C.foo` method is defined as `B => B`, not `C => C` as it is intended.

Comment: @Dima Good point although I'm not worried about another level of subclass. I've made `B` in my example final to clarify.

Comment: @MichaelMior the point is, that it is possible to circumvent this definition and create an instance of `A`, whose `foo` method does not return an instance of its class.

Comment: @Dima Right, but I don't care about that case, so it's not relevant to my question. (Although I didn't specify that in my initial ask.)

Comment: @Wellingr a slight improvement is to add `this: S =>` to the definition of trait `A`. This doesn't prevent Dima's case, but does prevent setting `S` to a type not present in the hierarchy of a concrete class or object implementing `A`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider type class solution

```
case class B(bar: Int)

// type class
trait Fooable[A] {
  def foo(x: A, y: A): A
}

// proof that B satisfies Fooable constraints
implicit val fooableB: Fooable[B] = new Fooable[B] {
  override def foo(x: B, y: B): B = B(x.bar + y.bar)
}

// a bit of syntax sugar to enable x foo y
implicit class FooableOps[A](x: A) {
  def foo(y: A)(implicit ev: Fooable[A]) = ev.foo(x,y)
}

val b1 = B(1)
val b2 = B(41)
b1.foo(b2)
// B(42)
```

which Scala 3 [simplifies](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/type-classes.html) to

```
case class B(bar: Int)

// type class
trait Fooable[A] {
  extension (x: A) def foo (y: A): A
}

// proof that B satisfies Fooable constraints + syntactic sugar
given Fooable[B] with
   extension (x: B) def foo (y: B): B = B(x.bar + y.bar) 


val b1 = B(1)
val b2 = B(41)
b1.foo(b2)
// B(42)
```

See Scala FAQ: [How can a method in a superclass return a value of the “current” type?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type)

Comment: The Scala 2 example is missing an object to wrap the implicits, but seems to work otherwise. However, this doesn't seem to allow something equivalent to another subclass of `A` as in my original example.

Comment: @MichaelMior It is a different technique were instead of subclassing we provide another "proof" that the new class satisfies the constraints. Say we want class `Zar` to gain `foo` capability, then we show `Fooable[Zar]`  is a given.

Comment: Suppose I implement `Fooable` for `B` and another class `C`. What would a valid type look like that could hold both `B` and `C` instances and provide access to the `foo` method?

Comment: @MichaelMior Given `Fooable[B]` and `Fooable[C]`, then `v` in `def f[A: Fooable](v: A) = ???` gains `foo` capability for both `f(new B)` and `f(new C)`.