# Scala can't find case class parameter in generic trait method

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have the following case class implementing a trait with a generic method. The goal is to have each class `S` which extends the trait implement the method in a way that the method consumes a parameter of type `S` and returns a value of type `S`.

```scala
case class Foo(x: Int) extends Bar {
  def baz[Foo](v: Foo): Foo = {
    Foo(v.x + x)
  }
}

trait Bar {
  def baz[S <: Bar](v: S): S
}
```

However, when compiling this, I get the following error that `x` cannot be found.

```
error: value x is not a member of type parameter Foo
    Foo(v.x + x)
          ^
one error found
```

Even stranger to me is that when I change the method to return `Foo(3)` (thus removing access to `x`), I get the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : <empty>.Foo
 required: Foo(in method baz)
    Foo(3)
       ^
one error found
```

I'm not sure what the types `<empty>.Foo` and `Foo(in method baz)` are and why both of these aren't just `Foo`. There's obviously some things about Scala's type system I'm misunderstanding, so help clearing that up would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I expect to have multiple classes implementing `Bar`. I want to be able to call `baz` on vals of type `Bar`.

Consider in the example below that `a` and `b` are obtained from elsewhere and I know based on the logic of my program that they are both instances of the same class (not necessarily `Foo`). Is there any way to make a legal call to `baz` in this case? I know I could cast both to `Foo`, but this happens in a scenario where I don't know what the specific class is. That is, I know both `a` and `b` are of type `T <: Bar` for the same `T`, but I don't know what `T` is.

```
object Foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a: Bar[_] = Foo(3)
    val b: Bar[_] = Foo(2)
    a.baz(b) // This call is invalid
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, it seems [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66856558/11882002) to an earlier question of yours suggested much the same thing as I did, and you accepted it. Did that not work for you?

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI I guess I was failing to see the connection between these two, but I think you're right that they are basically the same thing. Perhaps this should just be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I'd suggest typeclasses in that case (although they wouldn't work for your example because you're using wildcards there). I'd also recommend unaccepting my answer if it doesn't solve your question (I'm editing it, but someone else may answer until then)

Comment: Your sample seems like it's too complicated. I would opt out for F[_], it will solve your issue way less simpler

Comment: @user2963757 I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: I guess what you need is `trait Bar[T] {
  def baz(v: T): Bar[T]
}

case class Foo(x: Int) extends Bar[Int]{
  override def baz(v: Int) = Foo(v+x)
}`

Answer (score 3):

The type parameter for `baz` does not work the way you seem to think it does. In the original trait `Bar`, it's telling you that you can pass in *any* `S` that extends `Bar` and `baz` will output another `S`. That means that in `Foo`, you have to handle not only `Foo` but also other classes that inherit from `Bar`.

Furthermore, the type parameter `Foo` shadows the class `Foo`. It is equivalent to this:

```
case class Foo(x: Int) extends Bar {
  def baz[T](v: T): T = {
    Foo(v.x + 1)
  }
}
```

`T` is entirely unrelated to `Foo` and `Bar`, and so your method is also not satisfying `baz`'s signature, because it should really be `T <: Bar`.

What I think you want to do is have `S` by a type parameter given to `Bar` itself (this is called F-bounded polymorphism):

```
case class Foo(x: Int) extends Bar[Foo] {
  def baz(v: Foo): Foo = {
    Foo(v.x + 1)
  }
}

trait Bar[S <: Bar[S]] { this: S =>
  def baz(v: S): S
}
```

Here, the `S` can basically be used to refer to the type of the class extending `Bar`, so the compiler knows `baz` inputs and outputs `Foo`s.

You could later use it like this:

```scala
def test[T <: Bar[T]](a: T, b: T) = a.baz(b)
```

Based on your edit, though, it seems like you want a typeclass. I would suggest changing the definition of `Bar` to something like this:

```scala
trait Bar[T] {
  def baz(t: T): T
}
```

Then `Foo` could be defined like this:

```scala
case class Foo(x: Int)
```

An implicit instance of `Bar` for `Foo` would be provided separately (perhaps in `Bar`'s companion object):

```scala
object Bar {
  implicit val fooBar: Bar[Foo] = new Bar {
    def baz(v: Foo): Foo = Foo(v.x + 1)
  }
  //For convenience
  def apply[T](implicit bar: Bar[T]): bar
}
```

You could later use it like this:

```scala
def test[T : Bar](a: T, b: T) = Baz[T].bar(a, b)
```

See [Advantages of F-bounded polymorphism over typeclass for return-current-type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59813323) for more info.

Comment: Second one gives me `trait Bar takes type parameters`

Comment: @GuruStron My bad, let me fix it.

Comment: Given that the type parameter is now associated with the class, I don't see how I can call `baz` using two vals of type `Bar` which I *know* are actually instances of the same class without casting both to a specific class (e.g. `Foo`).

Comment: @MichaelMior I don't understand. Did you *want* to make `Foo` handle any subtype `S` of `Bar`? If so, I can change my answer, but could you edit your question to better explain what you mean?

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI Thanks for your patience. I edited my answer to try to clarify.

Comment: @MichaelMior By the way, I've updated my answer to include an example with type classes. Let me know if that works for you.